# Azure CosmosDB (Gremlin API), How to connect using Gremlin.Net

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am trying to use the Gremlin.Net NuGet package to connect to Azure CosmosDB (Gremlin API), using the Package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gremlin.Net

[image: GremlinClient]

On Azure Portal, I can obtain the *Key* (used on CosmosDB client NuGet packages: Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB and Microsoft.Azure.Graphs)

[image]

How can I obtain the ssl, port, *username* and *password* credentials to connect to Azure CosmosDB (Gremlin API) for use on the Gremlin.Net NuGet package?

Answer (score 6):

Since you are connecting to the public port of the gremlin server you can use the same information that they show in the docs to connect 
via the gremlin console [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-gremlin-console#ConnectAppService).

```
hosts: [your_database_server.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com]
port: 443
username: /dbs/your_database_account/colls/your_collection
password: your_primary_key
connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: true
}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

I was able to connect using the line below:

```
        var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer("XXX.graphs.azure.com", 443, true, "/dbs/your_database_account/colls/your_collection",
            "password");
```

Also if you are using .NET and Cosmos there is a Microsoft provided NuGet package called Microsoft.Azure.Graphs which is currently in preview.

Comment: What's the difference between Gremlin.NET and Microsoft.Azure.Graphs?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Graphs was the original driver that they put out as part of the CosmosDB preview.  Gremlin.NET is an open source driver for the Tinkerpop ecosystem and is now the recommended way to connect to the Cosmos Graph API

Answer (score 4):

Azure Cosmos DB team has announced they were no longer investing in any further release of Microsoft.Azure.Graphs versions. None ever went further the -preview stage. Some bugs were also reported in Microsoft.Azure.Graphs 0.3.1 -preview regarding float decimal conversion - e.g. as you would find in latitude&longitude conversion. Negative (-) hyphen were lost in conversion... Azure Cosmos DB team now strongly suggests using Gremlin.Net from now on. As mentioned earlier, the Gremlin.Net option used in Azure Cosmos DB doesn't support bytecode streams at this stage, so I guess we ought to be patient and give the runner a chance  In the meantime, you can still have a look at following links on how to use Gremlin.Net with Azure Cosmos DB Graph API

http://alexdrenea.com/2018/01/10/cosmosdb-graph-using-gremlin-net/

http://alexdrenea.com/2018/01/12/cosmosdb-with-gremlin-net-part-2/

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/439

Comment: Thank you for the info. It would be good if CosmosDB also supports Cypher Query Language / BOLT.

Comment: Yes indeed, that might be an interesting option. The idea has already been proposed and you're welcome to vote online at following link.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/19275547-support-cypher-as-a-query-language-for-graph-data

I already did though I spent the maximum amount of votes allowed...

Comment: By the way, here is also the link to the official sample for Cosmos DB + Gremlin.Net: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-gremlindotnet-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, you might be able to connect to Cosmos with the .net driver in theory, but even if you could, you wouldn't be able to traverse the graph because Cosmos currently doesn't support bytecode streams.

They were trying to get it out in the first part of this year, but the [github issue is kinda quiet at the time of my writing this.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/439)